# OpenGL: Fire event on new geometry creation

Tags: c, events, opengl

In specific I am working in linux environment. This is an opengl application. Upon a calculation of certain geometries, I want to be able to fire an event whenever a new geometry is created. Is there any .NET equivalent of events in C ??

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: This seems to be not related to OpenGL, as OpenGL itself does not provide any kind of event mechanism. Consider retagging the question.

Comment: @Malte Clasen - I do know that GLUT has events.  http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/

Comment: @sheepsimulator GLUT is an independent user interface library and not part of OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Events in C are implemented using [function callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142789/what-is-a-callback-in-c-and-how-are-they-implemented). The linked question has a couple answers that address how to code callbacks.

Comment: I have native C application in linux environement. More specifically, this is an OpenGL application. On the creation of certain input geometries, i want to be able to call an event, instead of calling a function explicitly. Is there anything analogous to events in .NET ??

Comment: @de costo - Please put that information in your actual question.

Comment: I added a link to my post. The answers in that other question describe using function pointers for callbacks (the 2nd answer is particularly relevant).

Answer (score 0):

With [gnome libraries](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Closures.html) or [gtk+](http://www.gtk.org/) (which is built on top of it)? You can do it all yourself with function pointers, but this is the only "standard" C library that I've personally used that standardized events and callbacks. There's probably others out there, too.

Answer (score 0):

To translate from .NET land:

An "event" is simply the calling of a function.  To make this configurable, you need to give the thing that generates the "event" a function pointer.  The function pointer is called, and is the thing that is "done" when the "event" occurs.

A thing to "do" is a function in C and C++.

If you only want to "do" one thing upon an "event".  You'd pass in a pointer to your function, which is the thing you want to "do" upon your "event" as a function pointer to the thing that causes the "event."  This is called a *callback*.  Other posts have lots of examples on how this works.

If you need to "do" *multiple* things on an "event", you'll need to use a signal/slot implementation like [boost::signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/signals.html).  Or if OpenGL has something similar, I'd use that.  In that case, you have *multiple callbacks*.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't say I'd really *recommend* using them, a *possible* alternative to callbacks would be signals.

You can use `signal` to say how a particular signal should be handled, and `raise` to send a particular signal. Note, however, that there are *serious* restrictions on what you can do in a signal handler. Lots of code isn't really written to deal well with signals, and quite a bit of it assumes that almost any signal implies such a serious problem that continued execution after a signal may be problematic.