# External callback function with portaudio

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I am currently working on a project using portaudio.

To make my code a little bit more readable, I would like to isolate the callback function in another `.c` file.
However, when I simply put the prototype and the code of the function in one `.h` and one `.c` files and that I include my `.h` file, my program can't find the callback function.

How should I do this?

Thank you in advance of your answer!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: Here is a good post on callbacks if you want to double check your implementation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142789/what-is-a-callback-in-c-and-how-are-they-implemented

Comment: Also, make sure you are compiling the new source into your program, or linking against it if you are compiling the new source into a library.