# "Type lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error when assigning function pointer (not == issue!)

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm working on an embedded C project that involves function callbacks using a function pointer. I'm weeded through all my code and created a simple example that produces the error in question. I've been staring at this for over an hour and still can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
/* Callback function pointer type for ADC Sample Interrupt */
typedef void (*ADC_Callback_Func)(uint16_t);

/* ADC Timer interrupt callback function pointer */
ADC_Callback_Func ADC_CallbackFunction(uint16_t sample);

/* ADC Callback function */
void ADC_SampleReceived(uint16_t sample);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize ADC Timer */
    ADC_CallbackFunction = &ADC_SampleReceived; //<-- Code Bombs here

    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1) {

    }
}

void ADC_SampleReceived(uint16_t sample)
{

}
```

Again, the error I receive after compiling is:

> "Type lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Comment: I think that you can use this post as a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142789/what-is-a-callback-in-c-and-how-are-they-implemented

Comment: Please double-check the error message. I get "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment". The phrase "type lvalue" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code `ADC_CallbackFunction` is not a function pointer. It is a function that takes a `uint16_t` and returns a function pointer.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean, but not quite sure how to fix it

Comment: OK. I found the incredibly STUIPID error I had. Since I'm declaring a function pointer, and not a function prototype, I don't need anything after the name of the variable. So ditching the parenthesis and parameter list seems to fix the problem. The new line is simply

Comment: ADC_Callback_Func ADC_CallbackFunction;

Comment: @immibis: Quite right. The similarity of the names threw me off. I'll delete my earlier comment.